# About std::basic_ostream::write

Tags: c++, file, stream, buffer

I'm reading up on the `write` method of `basic_ostream` objects and this is what I found on cppreference:

> ```
> basic_ostream& write( const char_type* s, std::streamsize count );
> ```
>
> Behaves as an `UnformattedOutputFunction`. After constructing and checking the sentry object, outputs the characters from successive locations in the character array whose first element is pointed to by `s`. Characters are inserted into the output sequence until one of the following occurs:
>
> - exactly `count` characters are inserted
> - inserting into the output sequence fails (in which case `setstate(badbit)` is called)

So I get that it writes a chunk of characters from a buffer into the stream. And the number of characters are the bytes specified by `count`. But there are a few things of which I'm not sure. These are my questions:

- Should I use `write` only when I want to specify *how many* bytes I want to write to a stream? Because normally when you print a `char` array it will print the entire array until it reaches the null byte, but when you use `write` you can specify how many characters you want written.

  ```
  char greeting[] = "Hello World";

  std::cout    << greeting;     // prints the entire string
  std::cout.write(greeting, 5); // prints "Hello"
  ```

  But maybe I'm misinterpreting something with this one.
- And I often see this in code samples that use `write`:

  ```
  stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer), sizeof(buffer));
  ```

  Why is the `reinterpret_cast` to `char*` being use? When should I know to do something like that when writing to a stream?

If anyone can help me with these two question it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> •Should I use write only when I want to specify how many bytes I want to write to a stream?

Yes - you should use `write` when there's a specific number of bytes of data arranged contiguously in memory that you'd like written to the stream in order.  But sometimes you might want a specific number of bytes and need to get them another way, such as by formatting a `double`'s ASCII representation to have specific width and precision.

Other times you might use `>>`, but that has to be user-defined for non builtin types, and when it is defined - normally for better but it may be worse for your purposes - it prints whatever the class designer choose, including potentially data that's linked from the object via pointers or references and static data of interest, and/or values calculated on the fly.  It may change the data representation: say converting binary `double`s to ASCII representations, or ensuring a network byte order regardless of the host's endianness.  It may also omit some of the object's data, such as cache entries, counters used to manage but not logically part of the data, array elements that aren't populated etc..

> Why is the reinterpret_cast to char* being use? When should I know to do something like that when writing to a stream?

The `write()` function signature expects a `const char*` argument, so this conversion is being done.  You'll need to use a cast whenever you can't otherwise get a `char*` to the data.

The cast reflects the way `write()` treats data starting at the first byte of the object as 8-bit values without any consideration of the actual pre-cast type of the data.  This ties in with being able to do things like say a `write()` of the last byte of a `float` and first 3 bytes of a `double` appearing next in the same structure - all the data boundaries and interpretation is lost after the `reinterpret_cast<>`.

(You've actually got to be more careful of this when doing a `read()` of bytes from an input stream... say you read data that constituted a `double` when written into memory that's not aligned appropriately for a `double`, then try to use it as a `double`, you may get a SIGBUS or similar alignment exception from your CPU or degraded performance depending on your system.)

Answer (score 1):

`basic_ostream::write` and its counterpart `basic_istream::read`, is used to perform unformatted I/O on a data stream. Typically, this is raw binary data which may or may not contain printable ascii characters.

The main difference between `read`/`write` and the other formatted operators like `<<`, `>>`, `getline` etc. is that the former doesn't make any assumptions on the data being worked on -- you have full control over what bytes get read from and written to the stream. Compared to the latter which may skip over whitespaces, discard or ignore them etc.

To answer your second question, the `reinterpret_cast <char *>` is there to satisfy the function signature and to work with the buffer a byte at a time. Don't let the type `char` fool you. The reason `char` is used is because it's the smallest builtin primitive type provided by the language. Perhaps a better name would be something like `uint8` to indicate it's really an unsigned byte type.

Comment: So by your explanation, theoretically you can pass a `bool*` to `reinterpret_cast` because it is also a byte?

Comment: @0x499602D2: it wouldn't be a type mismatch... a `bool*` is just like any other pointer... it has some number of bytes (normally 4 for a 32-bit app, 8 for 64-bit), and you can `reintrepret_cast` to to `char*` and start writing bytes from the address where the `bool` is stored.  In C++03 the size of a `bool` was unspecified, but C++11 introduced both a default and programmer control... there's nothing special about them and specifically a `bool*` is NOT some kind of pointer to a specific bit in memory (that would - if possible - make conversion to `char*` weird/lossy).